# Can't the two different methods to add_loss in Keras/Tensorflow be used together?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss

I wrote the following code to make a simple experiment through a Autoencoder, and I just wanna to use two losses, the first loss is the traditional MSE loss of the input and the output which is reconstructed from the latent vector of AE, and the second loss is the MSE loss between the two outputs of the symmetrical layers in encoder and the decoder, that is to say, if the AE have 5 layers, I want to add a MSE loss between the second layer and the fourth layer, for they are symmetrical.The code is here:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer, InputSpec
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, GaussianNoise, Layer, Activation
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

#build vae model

input_place = Input(shape=(128,))

e_layer1 = Dense(64,activation='relu')(input_place)
e_layer2 = Dense(32,activation='relu')(e_layer1)
hidden = Dense(16,activation='relu')(e_layer2)

d_layer1 = Dense(32,activation='relu')(hidden)
d_layer2 = Dense(64,activation='relu')(d_layer1)

output_place = Dense(128,activation='sigmoid')(d_layer2)

model = Model(inputs=input_place,outputs=output_place)

loss = K.mean(K.square(d_layer1 - e_layer2),axis = -1)

model.add_loss(loss)

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss=['mse'],
              metrics=['accuracy'])

input_data = np.random.randn(400,128)

model.fit(input_data,
          input_data,
          batch_size = 32,
          epochs=5)
```

but when I run this code, it occurs a error about

```
Epoch 1/5
 32/400 [=>............................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 1.6429 - acc: 0.0000e+00Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-eac3a65824ec>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/jishilun/Desktop/keras_loss_test.py', wdir='/Users/jishilun/Desktop')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/jishilun/Desktop/keras_loss_test.py", line 49, in <module>
    epochs=5)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 204, in fit_loop
    callbacks.on_batch_end(batch_index, batch_logs)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 115, in on_batch_end
    callback.on_batch_end(batch, logs)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 236, in on_batch_end
    self.totals[k] += v * batch_size

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,) (16,) (32,)
```

and if I remove the add_loss, the code can run, so I think the two methods to add_loss in Keras/Tensorflow can't be used together simply or it may have some changes(Maybe the question occurs from the mini-batch?)
Please help me! Any advice or suggestions will be welcome!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code runs perfectly here. Are you sure this is "your" code or you simplified it for asking? The problem seems to be just a shape mismatch.

Comment: ??It is my code really >_<,and under the batch_size 32 it can't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not from `add_loss()` but from your `batch_size`. Your input data is `(400,128)`, but `batch_size` is 32. Try to change it to a factoring number of 400, such as 40 or 20, and it will work.

Comment: I changed my code by your suggestions and the code can work, thank you! But I still have a question: if the number of samples is a prime number and it is big( may be more than 5000), how should I run the code?? I think if the batch_size is too large( equal to the number of samples) the memory of GPU will overflow.

Comment: This is probably a version specific bug. I assure you that the code you posted runs perfectly here without any change.

Comment: @FlightPanda24 It should be ok if you get rid of some samples of the last batch.

Comment: @DanielMöller What’s your version of keras? I curious why fit method doesn’t have an argument like “keep_reminder” or something to flag whether we should keep reminder.

Comment: What is "keep_reminder"? Remainder? Usually it just runs a smaller batch at the end. It's Keras 2.3.0

Comment: So how should I avoid the last batch? I think changing some parameters simply in the fit() function can not do with it. Can you give me a sample?Thanks!

Comment: @ Daniel Möller I find my Keras version is 2.2.4 currently, maybe I should update my Keras version. But I still wanna to know how to get rid of samples in the last batch.

Comment: See comment above.

Comment: @ Daniel Möller It can work, but I think by doing this the integrity of data will be damaged. So if we don't ignore the last batch, how to deal with the error??